# Post data to Firebase from Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use the Angular 4 and AngularFire to send data to Firebase.

I need to get a few data like: name, country, zip-code with email and password.

After update: //

The HTML FORM :

```
<form #formData='ngForm' (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formData)">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Name" (ngModel)="name" name="name" class="txt" required>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Country" (ngModel)="country" name="country" class="txt" required>
 <input type="text" placeholder="code" (ngModel)="code" name="code" class="txt" required>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Email addres" (ngModel)="email" name="email" class="txt" required>
 <input type="password" placeholder="Password" (ngModel)="password" name="password" class="txt" required>
 <button type="submit" [disabled]="!formData.valid" class="basic-btn">Create Account</button>
</form>
```

I use the model to get value and use the code to send it:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

onSubmit(formData) {
 if(formData.valid) {
 console.log(formData.value);
 this.db.auth.createUser({
  email: formData.value.email,
  password: formData.value.password
 }).then (
   (state: AngularFireAuth) => {
    this.db.object('/users/' + state.uid).set({code: formData.value.code});
    this.router.navigate(['/login'])
  }).catch(
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      this.error = err;
    })
 }
}
```

And I get error in:
The datebase don't have auth, FireAuth also don't have `createUser`

this.db.auth.createUser

And at this there is no `uid` property

this.db.object('/users/' + state.uid).set({code: formData.value.code});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to save extra data in the auth part of Firebase. You can save all extra information in database itself under user with same uid as in authentication part.

```
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

onSubmit(formData) {
 if(formData.valid) {
  console.log(formData.value);
  this.af.auth.createUser({
    email: formData.value.email,
    password: formData.value.password
  }).then (
    (state: FirebaseAuthState) => {
      db.object('/users/' + state.uid).set({zip: formData.value.zip});
      this.router.navigate(['/login'])
    }).catch(
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        this.error = err;
      })
   }
}
```

Comment: i got:


ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'OpaqueToken', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol FirebaseUserConfig in E:/DEV/project/zmotywowanych/node_modules/angularfire2/tokens.d.ts, resolving symbol AngularFireModule.initializeApp in E:/DEV/project/zmotywowanych/node_modules/angularfire2/angularfire2.d.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in E:/DEV/project/../app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in E:/DEV/project/../app.module.ts

Comment: What is your AngularFire version?

Comment: "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.7-pre",

Comment: Try with "2.0.0-beta.8"

Comment: It is a known angularfire issue. Try to reinstall firebase libraries `npm uninstall firebase angularfire2 --save
npm install firebase angularfire2 --save`. The issue is here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/843

Comment: Then i unistall them and install they cant find 
import { AngularFire, AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseAuthState } from 'angularfire2';
This 3 ...

Comment: Looks like you have installed latest version. Make changes like here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/854